# Error en funcion obtener mes con java

Tags: java, funciones

Estoy realizando un código Java con funciones para un curso que estoy realizando.

El código está funcionando, pero al momento de mostrar los resultados, me muestra el mensaje y debajo del mensaje me aparece el numero del mes.

Por ejemplo, si presiono 1, me aparece el mensaje correspondiente,  debajo me aparece  el mensaje corresponde al mes de enero y debajo de ese mensaje me pone el numero ingresado. No quiero que aparezca ese mensaje.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Ingrese un numero del 1 al 12");
   int n1 = op.nextInt();

  System.out.println(mes(n1));
}

public static int mes(int n1)
{
    switch (n1) {
     case 1:System.out.println("El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Enero");
       break;
       case 2:System.out.println("El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Febrero");
       break;
       case 3:System.out.println("El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Marzo");
       break;
       case 4:System.out.println("El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Abril");
       break;
       case 5:System.out.println("El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Mayo");
       break;
       case 6:System.out.println("El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Junio");
       break;
       case 7:System.out.println("El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Julio");
       break;
       case 8:System.out.println("El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Agosto");
       break;
       case 9:System.out.println("El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Septiembre");
       break;
       case 10:System.out.println("El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Octubre");
       break;
       case 11:System.out.println("El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Noviembre");
       break;
       case 12:System.out.println("El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Diciembre");
       break;
    default: System.out.println("Mes Inexistente");
             break;
    }
    return n1;
}
```

Comment: Leí tu pregunta y no me aclaro bien cuál es la salida exacta que esperas, sugiero que la edites y coloques un ejemplo de la salida que esperas obtener. Un saludo.

Answer (score 6):

El problema lo tienes en el retorno de la función.

`System.out.println(mes(n1));`

Esa línea lo que hace es que va a imprimir en pantalla el retorno de la función `mes()`. En tu caso, al devolver `n1` estás imprimiendo el contenido de dicha variable además de los `System.out.println();` que se ejecutan dentro de la función.

Tienes dos opciones:

**Opción 1**

Definir la función `public static int mes(int n1)` como `public static void mes(int n1)` eliminar el `return` de la función y llamar a la función directamente, sin un `System.out.println()`.

En este caso lo único que se imprimiría por pantalla sería el texto del `case` que corresponde según el valor de `n1`.

Esta solución no me termina de gustar, ya que en la medida de lo posible se debería evitar hacer salidas a pantalla desde dentro de funciones.

**Opción 2**

No imprimir nada por pantalla desde dentro de la función y que esta devuelva el texto a imprimir para que sea la llamada a la función la que imprima el resultado.

```
System.out.println(mes(n1));

public static String mes(int n1)
{
  String mensaje = ''; 

  switch (n1) {
     case 1:mensaje = "El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Enero";
       break;
       case 2:mensaje = "El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Febrero";
       break;
       case 3:mensaje = "El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Marzo";
       break;
       case 4:mensaje = "El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Abril";
       break;
       case 5:mensaje = "El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Mayo";
       break;
       case 6:mensaje = "El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Junio";
       break;
       case 7:mensaje = "El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Julio";
       break;
       case 8:mensaje = "El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Agosto";
       break;
       case 9:mensaje = "El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Septiembre";
       break;
       case 10:mensaje = "El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Octubre";
       break;
       case 11:mensaje = "El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Noviembre";
       break;
       case 12:mensaje = "El número ingresado corresponde al mes de Diciembre";
       break;
    default: mensaje = "Mes Inexistente";
             break;
    }
    return mensaje;
}
```

Comment: yo pondría el texto inmutable en un string y los meses en un array para sacar con el int, asi no necesitará switch/case... aunque igual es imperativo usarlo en el curso que realiza

Comment: @lois6b Sí, esa sería una mucho mejor solución. Pero en mis respuestas me gusta modificar lo mínimo el código del **OP** por si necesita el código de dicha manera por algo o para no echar por tierra todo el trabajo que ha realizado hasta que se atascó.

Answer (score 2):

Lo tienes en la llamada a `System.out.println(mes(n1));`

Estas ejecutando la función y imprimiendo lo que devuelve el metodo `mes()`. Si quieres que no se imprima el numero pasado por consola, modificalo así `mes(n1)`

Comment: Muchas gracias.. Realizando esa modificacion funciono como lo deseaba...